# How to use grep to get anything just after `name=`?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I’m stuck in trying to grep anything just after `name=`, include only spaces and alphanumeric.

e.g.:

```
name=some value here
```

I get

```
some value here
```

I’m totally newb in this, the following grep match everything including the `name=`.

```
grep 'name=.*' filename
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `echo 'name=some value here' | grep -Po 'name=\K[ A-Za-z0-9]*'`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

As detailed [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you want a positive lookbehind clause, such as:

```
grep -P '(?<=name=)[ A-Za-z0-9]*' filename
```

The -P makes grep use the Perl dialect, otherwise you'd probably need to escape the parentheses. You can also, as noted elsewhere, append the `-o` parameter to print out only what is matched. The part in brackets specifies that you want alphanumerics and spaces.

The advantage of using a positive lookbehind clause is that the "name=" text is not part of the match. If grep highlights matched text, it will only highlight the alphanumeric (and spaces) part. The -o parameter will also not display the "name=" part. And, if you transition this to another program like sed that might capture the text and do something with it, you won't be capturing the "name=" part, although you can also do that by using capturing parenthess.

Comment: does grep actually support positive lookbehind?

Comment: I was worried about that, too, so I tried it on my Windows PC, and that is why I had to use the -P parameter. It probably supports it in the other flavors (maybe not -G), but I didn't know the proper escaping for the elements. I'm using grep 2.5.1.

Comment: I get this with grep -P:
    grep: Support for the -P option is not compiled into this

This is on Ubuntu Hardy (Linux 2.6.24).  On another Linux machine it failed with a slightly different error message, and likewise on Solaris 10.

Comment: Yep, read up a bit on this, it's an experimental option that a lot of operating systems don't include by default yet. 

As for highlighting machine text, grep --color does that too :)

Comment: I thought that I might need to use `sed` to get what I need. I know the -P is not compiled in some of the machine out there, but anyway its in my mach and it does what I need. Really thanks a lot for this. Never thought of positive lookbehind.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Does work if you install gnu grep i.e. brew install grep --default-names

Comment: Yep, but you have to install the GNU grep (Brew or Port)

Comment: i usually prefer the less cumbersome `\K` pattern as its easier for me to read, e.g. `grep -oP 'name=\K[ A-Za-z0-9]*' filename`. also, the [perl docs claim a performance benefit](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions) with `\K`. not sure if that applies to PCRE engines in general or the perl implementation alone

Comment: Without `-P` you don't have lookbehind at all. So it is rather mandatory.

Comment: Seems like -P isn't supported out of the box on whatever grep flavor ships with mac

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
sed -n 's/^name=//p' filename
```

It tells sed to print nothing (-n) by default, substitute your prefix with nothing, and print if the substitution occurs.

Bonus: if you really need it to only match entries with only spaces and alphanumerics, you can do that too:

```
sed -n 's/^name=\([ 0-9a-zA-Z]*$\)/\1/p' filename
```

Here we've added a pattern to match spaces and alphanumerics only until the end of the line ($), and if we match we substitute the group in parentheses and print.

Comment: Most likely a very suitable solution, but the asker asked about grep... and it doesn't match only spaces and alphanumerics.

Comment: Matching only spaces and alphas is trivial, I'll add something for that.  As for only using grep, well, the top-ranked answer right now uses grep AND sed...at least this only uses a single process.  :)

Comment: I love your answer too, as I’m also messing with `sed` now. Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 7):

grep does not extract like you expect. What you need is

```
grep "name=" file.txt | cut -d'=' -f1-
```

Answer (score 7):

gawk

```
echo "name=some value here" | awk -F"=" '/name=/ { print $2}'
```

or with bash

```
str="name=some value here"
IFS="="
set -- $str
echo $1    
unset IFS
```

or

```
str="name=some value here"
str=${str/name=/}
```

Answer (score 1):

grep will print the entire line where it matches the pattern. To print only the pattern matched, use the grep -o option. You'll probably also need to use sed to remove the name= part of the pattern.

```
grep -o 'name=[0-9a-zA-Z ]'  myfile | sed /^name=/d
```

Comment: Two processes for this is excessive.  If you have to use sed, may as well do it with that alone.