# grep: group capturing

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have following string:

```
{"_id":"scheme_version","_rev":"4-cad1842a7646b4497066e09c3788e724","scheme_version":1234}
```

and I need to get value of "scheme version", which is 1234 in this example.

I have tried

```
grep -Eo "\"scheme_version\":(\w*)"
```

however it returns

```
"scheme_version":1234
```

How can I make it? I know I can add **sed** call, but I would prefer to do it with single grep.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with only 'grep'. A couple of years ago I did a lot with string manipulation, often piping greps to stuff like 'sed', or 'cut'. I'd suggest you study 'piping' and the 'cut' command.

Comment: I don't use grep very often, but perhaps you can use a look-behind expression, as outlined in the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247812/im-stuck-in-trying-to-grep-anything-just-after-name.

Comment: Use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo '{"_id":"scheme_version","_rev":"4-cad1842a7646b4497066e09c3788e724","scheme_version":1234}' |
sed -n 's/.*"scheme_version":\([^}]*\)}/\1/p'
1234
```

Sorry it's not **grep**, so disregard this solution if you like.

Or stick with grep and add:

```
grep -Eo "\"scheme_version\":(\w*)"| cut -d: -f2
```

Comment: It seems it is best available option for me.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.


Works great to get "scheme_version" value but does not work to get "_id" value.


This sed expression worked for me, i'm hading it to answers : `sed -n 's/.*"scheme_version":["]*\([^(",})]*\)[",}].*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 71):

You'll need to use a look behind assertion so that it isn't included in the match:

```
grep -Po '(?<=scheme_version":)[0-9]+'
```

Comment: Hmm I got grep: Support for the -P option is not compiled into this --disable-perl-regexp binary

Comment: @Stipa Without PCRE support you cannot do what you want with grep as it does not support backreferences i.e. `\1`

Comment: Exactly what was asked, worked as a charm that "positive lookbehind"

Comment: Better than the accepted answer by a long shot for those of us lucky enough to have `-P` support already compiled in (or stubborn enough to rebuild grep...) :)

Comment: When you've multiple named groups, each of them is output in a new line. is there a way to print it on the same line? e.g. `cat ~/mydoc | grep -Po '(?<=blah">)[^<]*|(?<=bleh"></span>)[^<]*'` prints the captures in different lines.

Comment: hi from 2022 this does not work on mac because grep -E flag is not valid in damn macs

Comment: strange as -E flag is documented here: https://ss64.com/osx/grep.html. You can also try to see if "egrep" is available.

Answer (score 49):

I would recommend that you use [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for the job. jq is a command-line JSON processor.

```
$ cat tmp
{"_id":"scheme_version","_rev":"4-cad1842a7646b4497066e09c3788e724","scheme_version":1234}

$ cat tmp | jq .scheme_version
1234
```

Answer (score 34):

As an alternative to the positive lookbehind method suggested by SiegeX, you can reset the match starting point to directly after `scheme_version":` with the `\K` escape sequence.  E.g.,

```
$ grep -Po 'scheme_version":\K[0-9]+'
```

This restarts the matching process after having matched `scheme_version":`, and tends to have far better performance than the positive lookbehind.  Comparing the two on regexp101 demonstrates that the reset match start method takes 37 steps and 1ms, while the positive lookbehind method takes 194 steps and 21ms.

You can compare the performance yourself on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4YE54Z/1) and you can read more about resetting the match starting point in the [PCRE documentation](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#resetmatchstart).

Answer (score 9):

To avoid using `grep`s PCRE feature which is available in [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), but not in [BSD version](https://man.openbsd.org/grep), another method is to use [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), e.g.

```
$ rg -o 'scheme_version.?:(\d+)' -r '$1' <file.json 
1234
```

> `-r` Capture group indices (e.g., `$5`) and names (e.g., `$foo`).

Another example with Python and [`json.tool` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) which can validate and pretty-print:

```
$ python -mjson.tool file.json | rg -o 'scheme_version[^\d]+(\d+)' -r '$1'
1234
```

Related: [Can grep output only specified groupings that match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13466/21471)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$ echo '{"_id":"scheme_version","_rev":"4-cad1842a7646b4497066e09c3788e724","scheme_version":1234}' | awk -F ':' '{print $4}' | tr -d '}'
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

Improving @potong's answer that works only to get "scheme_version", you can use this expression :

```sh
$ echo '{"_id":"scheme_version","_rev":"4-cad1842a7646b4497066e09c3788e724","scheme_version":1234}' | sed -n 's/.*"_id":["]*\([^(",})]*\)[",}].*/\1/p'
scheme_version

$ echo '{"_id":"scheme_version","_rev":"4-cad1842a7646b4497066e09c3788e724","scheme_version":1234}' | sed -n 's/.*"_rev":["]*\([^(",})]*\)[",}].*/\1/p'
4-cad1842a7646b4497066e09c3788e724

$ echo '{"_id":"scheme_version","_rev":"4-cad1842a7646b4497066e09c3788e724","scheme_version":1234}' | sed -n 's/.*"scheme_version":["]*\([^(",})]*\)[",}].*/\1/p'
1234
```