# Gnuwin Grep only value

Tags: sed, grep, gawk

Example I have ver.txt

```
#tac
version=xxx
```

I want to display only xxx.

I can try grep, sed, gawk.Just want to learn how to make it.

Comment: I didn't try something special.Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247812/im-stuck-in-trying-to-grep-anything-just-after-name few solutions there.They were for linux.Anyways tried all of them but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the awk answer:

```
awk -F = '$1=="version" {print $2}' file
```

Sed

```
sed -n '/^version=/s///p' file
```

If you are running these commands from a windows command prompt, then single quote is not a valid grouping character, you may have to do this

```
awk -F = "$1==\"version\" {print $2}" file
```

Comment: Getting Unknown Command : `'' error.

Comment: For what? awk? Then use gawk.

Comment: Getting this error,                                                   awk : ^invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: Oh dam, I found the whole problem.Show extensions options closed.I keep renaming file ver.txt.txt it worked very well.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways is to use `grep` interpreting the pattern as a `perl` regular expression, and use a positive look-behind:

```
grep -oP '(?<=version=).*' infile
```