# How to retrieve a string which is located after a pattern in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a large file. I want to retrieve the word that is exactly after this string: "PatterStr()."

Two sample lines:

```
PatterStr().123232424 hhhhh 9999.  test, test32312
66666666698977.         PatterStr().8888
```

The output should be:

```
123232424
8888
```

when I use grep the whole line will be printed
And when two patterns are find in a line, both should be printed, for instance:

```
PatterStr().123232424 hhhhh 9999.  test, test32312.  PatterStr().11111111
66666666698977.         PatterStr().8888
```

the correct result:

```
123232424
11111111
8888
```

Comment: You mentioned `when I use grep the whole line will be printed And when two patterns are find in a line` in your question; thanks for letting us know that you have tried few things in order to solve this problem. It is always advisable to add code which you have tried in your question, since we all are here to learn, request you to please add the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/PatterStr\(\)\.[0-9]+/)){
    value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    sub(/.*\./,"",value)
    print value
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    value=""
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
123232424
11111111
8888
```

***Explanation of above code:*** Adding detailed level of explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                              ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  while(match($0,/PatterStr\(\)\.[0-9]+/)){        ##Starting while loop which has match function to match regex of PatterStr(). till all digits here.
    value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                ##Creating variable value which has sub-string value of current line, startin point RSTART tioll RLENGTH.
    sub(/.*\./,"",value)                           ##Substituting everything till DOT with NULL in variable value here.
    print value                                    ##Printing variable value here.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                   ##Setting rest of sub-string value starting from RSTART+RLENGTH to last of line of current line here.
    value=""                                       ##Nullify variable value here.
  }
}'  Input_file                                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the output of grep with the option *-o* or *--only-matching*. This will print only the matched parts of a matching line. To suppress the output of *PatterStr()* you can use a *LookBehind* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247824/1476909).

```
cat bigfile | grep -Po '(?<=PatterStr\(\)\.)[\w]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

This line does what you need

```
grep 'PatterStr()' large-file | sed "s/ /\n/g" | grep 'PatterStr()' | cut -f2 -d\.
```

Output:

```
123232424
11111111
8888
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how you can achieve this, you can for example do it with sed:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' text-file.txt | sed -n 's/^PatterStr()\.\(.*\)/\1/p'
```

The first sed will split the content to separate lines by replacing space by new line, the second will match the lines with PatterStr(). and print what comes directly after it.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of ORS we get a "\n" after each statement on each line.

```
awk -F'[. ]' 'NR == 1{print $2 ORS $NF}NR == 2{print $NF}' file

123232424
11111111
8888
```

Comment: Would be nice if you added some explanation